# HTML form to use PHP to write to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need the following form to right to MySQL table "table1" and columns "name" "email" and "comment".

```
<form method="post" action="sign.php" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                <fieldset>

                    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">


                    <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="email">

                    <label for="comment">Your Comments</label>
                    <input id="comment" type="text" placeholder="Your Comments" name="comment">

                 <a href="thanks.html" button type="submit" class="pure-button">SUBMIT</button>
                 </a>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

My PHP File looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myUser = "dbuser";
$myPassd = "********";
$myDB = "dbname";
$myserver = "192.168.1.80:3306";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// Create connection
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($myserver,$myUser,$myPassd) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL"); 
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
//if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
//echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
//}
//echo "connected";

$sql = "INSERT INTO signatures (name, comment) VALUES ( $name, $comment)";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "record added";

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I also need this to redirect to another html page after it run.

Comment: `<a href="thanks.html" button type="submit` - ? `( $name, $comment)` those are string values; quote them. `mysql_error()` should have thrown you an error, one you didn't include in your post.

Comment: I'm hoping that you know something about SQL-injection. This code is very dangerous. Please use PDO and prepare statements. You can find good examples and explanations on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: Use `<script>location.href = toNewPage.ext </script>` for redirection

Comment: Any way you could write out that code for me. This isnt something i normally do and ive gone though so many sites trying to figure this out that i think i have just confused myself now. I just need to store name email and comment into my database. it doesnt want to pass the values. i know i need to add my .php to the top form line also. Its sign.php

Comment: top line is: <form action="sign.php method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting and where in your code do they occur?

Comment: the main error i was getting seems like it wasnt working with the assigend valuse in the php files. when i input everything manually and run the script it writes just fine

Comment: '$name' - but see other answers too

Comment: @ChrisMcDowell when your question needs updating whether it be for content, or code you should edit it.

Comment: so it doesnt look like its executing the php file. its just sending me right to the thanks.html page.

Comment: the site is signrevis.com and its the form at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves your posting problems:

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="sign.php" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">

      ... your HTML ...
             <a  href="javascript:document.getElementById('form').submit()" class="pure-button">SUBMIT</button>
             </a>
```

Use the following for PDO queries to your database (safer!).

```
function openDBConnection()
{
   $myUser = "dbuser";
   $myPassd = "********";
   $myDB = "dbname";
   $myserver = "192.168.1.80";
   $port = 3306;

    try 
    {
     //this line was just updated!
        $dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$myserver;port=$port;dbname=$myDB", $myUser, $myPassd, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
    }
    catch( PDOException $Exception ) 
    {
         echo ("Unable to connect to database.");
         exit;
    }       
    return $dbConn;
}

function doPDOQuery($sql, $type, $var = array(), $dbname, $fetch = false)
{
    $db = openDBConnection();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //Prepare and query are two types, please use prepare.
    if ($type == "prepare")
    {
        $queryArray = array();
        if ($var != null)
        {
            foreach ($var as $key => $queryItem)
            {
                $queryArray[$key] = $queryItem;
            }
        }
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($queryArray);
    }
    else if ($type == "query")
    {
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("Supplied type is not valid.");
        exit;
    }
    if (!$sth)
    {
        $error = $db->errorInfo();
        echo($error[2]);
        exit;
    }

//$fetch: set to true when you expect results, set to false (default) when you do update/delete/insert and there are no records returned. Else the records are returned through $sth->fetchAll();
    if (!$fetch)
    {
        return $sth->rowCount();
    }
    return $sth->fetchAll();        
}
```

Example query for your database entry

```php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$SQL = "
        INSERT INTO signatures (name, email, comment) VALUES ( :name, :email, :comment);
    ";
    $result = doPDOQuery($SQL, "prepare", array(":name" => $name, ":comment" => $comment, ":email" => $email), $myDB, false);
```

Please read into PDO. It works as following:

1. DB connection is made
2. SQL is prepared by the SQL server
3. The params are loaded into the SQL query (supplied by the array).
4. Params are escaped which makes SQL-injection less possible.

Comment: getting a syntax error on:        $dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$myserver';port='.$port';dbname='.$myDB, $myUser, $myPassd, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));

Comment: thanks for the update. now this line is doing it: $result = doPDOQuery($SQL, "prepare", array(":name" => $name, ":comment" => $comment, :email => $email), $myDB, false);

Comment: Put `:email` between double quotes `":email"` (Code is updated)

Comment: not getting any errors anymore and its redirecting me to the correct page but not writing to the db

Comment: could it be the way the form is written? java is out of the question for me to use as im just using apache, php, and mysql. no way to use java

Comment: Please use a dev tool (F12) to sniff out how your code was sent to the database and which response is send back from the server. Did it return (echoed) any of my error codes?

Comment: so it doesnt look like its executing the php file. its just sending me right to the thanks.html page. –

Comment: Delete the location redirect for now and try again.

Comment: its saying webpage is not available. address bar shows the correct file.

Comment: Last code for now then: add this to the php code (should execute last) -> `echo '<script>location.href = "thanks.html"</script>'`

Comment: No problem. Please keep using the PDO for database entries! It's a lot safer.